# How to get UsersPublisher join model working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, join, many-to-many

I have three models: User, Publisher and Interest all with many to many relationships linked through three join models but only 2 out of 3 join models record the id's of their 2 parent models. my UsersPublisher model does not link User to Publisher.

My Interestscontroller proccesses a form (see code) through which I ask the user to provide Interest and Publisher. The latter gets processed via the [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) method which allows you to pass Publisher attributes via the InterestsController. the UsersPublisher join model records the user_id but the publisher_id is nil.

I've tried putting @users_publishers in  both the new and create methods of  Publishers- and InterestsController. My latest attempt of using after_action in the InterestsController (see code) has also failed. I've also tried the after_action way in the PublishersController

Your helped is highly appreciated!

**The UsersPublisher join model**

```
class UsersPublisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :publisher
end
```

**InterestsController**

```
class InterestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_user
after_action  :upublisher, only: [:new]

  def index
  @interests = policy_scope(Interest)
end

def show
  @interest = Interest.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@interest = Interest.new
@interest.publishers.build
authorize @interest
end

def create
  @interest = Interest.new(interest_params)
  @users_interests = UsersInterest.create(user: current_user, interest: @interest)
  authorize @interest
    if @interest.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
        end
        flash[:notice] = 'Thank you, we will be in touch soon'
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render }
        format.html { render :new }
      end
  end
end

def edit
  @interest = Interest.find(params[:id])
  authorize @interest
end

def update
  @interest = Interest.find(params[:id])
  @interest.update(interest_params)
  if @interest.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Your interest has been added'

  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Oops something went wrong'
  end
end

private

  def interest_params
    params.require(:interest).permit(:name, publishers_attributes: [:publisher,:id, :feed])
  end

  def find_user
    @user = current_user
  end

def upublisher
   @users_publishers = UsersPublisher.create(publisher: @publisher, user: current_user)
end

end
```

**Form**

```
 <%= form_for [@user, @interest] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :publishers do |ff| %>
     <%= ff.label :publisher %>
     <%= ff.text_field :publisher %>
     <%= ff.label :feed %>
     <%= ff.text_field :feed %>
   <%end%>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<%end%>
```

Comment: So much code - you should consider cutting it down so people can actually see what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks Rich, I've cut it down. Hope it's more understandable now :)

Comment: Thanks man, let me have a look!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `fields_for`, you'll want to make sure you have [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class UsersPublisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :publisher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :publisher
end
```

This should fix your issue (if it's as you outlined).

Your question is pretty broad, so I don't know whether the above will work. Below are my notes...

---

From the looks of it, your structure is very complicated; you should work to make it as simple as possible. In the case of creating "interests", you may wish to get rid of the form completely:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :publishers do
   resources :interests, path: "interest", only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/publishers/:publisher_id/interest
end

#app/controllers/interests_controller.rb
class InterestsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_publisher

   def create
      current_user.interests.create publisher: @publisher
   end

   def destroy
      @interest = current_user.interests.find_by publisher_id: @publisher.id
      current_user.interests.delete @interest
   end

   private

   def set_publisher
      @publisher = UserPublisher.find params[:publisher_id]
   end

end
```

You'd be able to use the above as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Add Interest", publisher_interest_path(@publisher), method: :post %>
<%= link_to "Remove Interest", publisher_interest_path(@publisher), method: :delete %>
```

Thinking about it properly, you've got a pretty bad structure.

---

I'd do something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :interests
   has_many :publishers, through: :interests
end

#app/models/interest.rb
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :publisher
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :publisher
end

#app/models/publisher.rb
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :interests,
   has_many :users, through: :interests
end
```

This should give you the ability to create `interests` for any number of `users` and `publishers`. If you create a `publisher` for a specific user, you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to pass the appropriate data:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :interest, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] #-> url.com/users/:user_id/interests/new
end

#app/controllers/interests_controller.rb
class InterestsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user     = User.find params[:user_id]
      @interest = @user.interests.new 
      @interest.publisher.build
   end

   def create
      @user     = User.find params[:user_id]
      @interest = @user.interests.new interest_params
   end

   private

   def interest_params
      params.require(:interest).permit(:user, :publisher)
   end
end 

#app/views/interests/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@user, @interest] do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :publisher do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```